# Скопировать в std:vector структуру по указателю

Tags: c++

```
void CM_Add(struct MyMessen* mes) {
    std::vector<struct MyMessen> res;

    res.push_back(???);
}
```

Вместо ??? нужно вставить содержимое mes,

НО! Указатель не должен влиять на элементы вектора!!!

Comment: Для начала переименуйте ваш `mes` и `mes` разными именами, а потом `mes.push_back(*structPtr);`. Но только не понятно зачем заполнять вектор который будет уничтожен при выходе из функции.

Comment: @LLENN извините, опечатался

Comment: @LLENN *structPtr в моем случае *mes???

Comment: Угу. Еще, нет смысла писать здесь `struct`. Можно просто `MyMessen *mes` и т.д.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat спасибо, С хорошо знаю. А вот C++ местами плохо понимаю. struct писать привычка :3

Comment: Странно, что при словах "С хорошо знаю" вы не знаете о разыменовании указателя.

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо ***@LLENN*** и ***@HolyBlackCat***!

Правильно так:

```
void CM_Add(struct MyMessen* mes) {
    std::vector<struct MyMessen> res;

    res.push_back(*mes);
}
```